# The assembly stdformat.dll cannot be specified for both /link and /reference compiler options

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Currently converting a VB6 project to C#.NET using Visual Studios 2012. When compiling I'm getting the following error message:

```
The assembly 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.StdFormat\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.stdformat.dll'
cannot be specified for both /link and /reference compiler options
```

I have tried to get rid of anything to do with COM interops and StdFormat (though not sure of how successful) and at a point of not knowing where to go from here.
Anyone have any idea?

Comment: the first place I'd do is right click on your project, and click properties, and see if anything is off

Comment: Been looking at it but don't really see anything amiss. Anything you can think of that could cause something like this?

Comment: well, the most obvious choice would be to find those compiler options that the error is about and make sure that they don't both refer to that dll

Comment: Thanks, you got the answer. Don't know how but seems VS or VBUC referenced the same DLL (stdformat.dll or microsoft.stdformat.dll) for some reason. Getting rid of it cleared the problem.